# why my segue didn't work?on Xcode objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

i am new to this and i try to change the text of a textfield in another view controller , and i just write something like this in prepare for segue,

---

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    secondViewcontroller *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        transferViewController.IDtextfield.text = @"1";   
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"2"]){
        transferViewController.IDtextfield.text= @"2";
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"3"]){
        transferViewController.IDtextfield.text = @"3";
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"4"]){
        transferViewController.IDtextfield.text = @"4";    
    }
}
```

---

can anyone tell me if there is anything wrong ?

Comment: Did you set storyboard segue identifier in "Storyboard"?

Comment: **What** is not working?

Comment: How are you pushing the view controllers. Show the code please.

Comment: @cylau97 : Did it work ?? What was the issue ?? If any of the answers below helped you ?? Please consider accepting the answer if it worked.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari it finally work, thank you all for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            SecondViewController *transferViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    transferViewController.data = @"1";
        }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"2"])
        {
            SecondViewController *transferViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    transferViewController.data = @"2";
        }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"3"])
        {
            SecondViewController *transferViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    transferViewController.data = @"3";
        }
    else{
            SecondViewController *transferViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    transferViewController.data = @"4";
        }

}
```

SecondViewController.h

```
 @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
         @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* data;
 @end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    IDtextfield.text = self.data;
}
```

**NOTE:** When you are creating the object of VC, it simply creates the reference of that VC i.e. when you creating the object of SecondVC, it doesn't load the complete controllers into memory. That means, TextField is not in memory, thats why you can not set the text of textField until the VC is not loaded.

Here, I just send the data which I wanted to set in the textfield, after the VC is loaded, I set the textfield text.

Answer (score 0):

Try Syntax like that:-

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller

        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the old-fashioned syntax and using dot syntax does not cause the error.